# My MySQL transaction didn't complete, and it's stuck in the middle

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

Now I'm getting errors like:

```
OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the process that may be responsible for locking the table.

Comment: how? how do i do that in mysql

Comment: I should have specified, kill the Python process by finding it with ps -ef command in your unix terminal. Alternatively to kill a mysql process type "SHOW PROCESSLIST" and then "KILL XYZID